# How to create android project with gradle from command line?

Tags: android, gradle, command-line

How to create android project with `gradle` from command line (**without any IDE**)?

[Before it was with `android` util like below](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

```
android create project --target 1 --name MyAndroidApp --path ./MyAndroidAppProject --activity MyAndroidAppActivity --package com.example.myandroid
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470831/how-to-use-gradle-to-generate-eclipse-and-intellij-project-files-for-android-pro

Comment: There is ongoing work to do this.  Look at: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/build-initialisation.md

Comment: Finally Android SDK has gradle template

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Similar to [How to create Java gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017364/how-to-create-java-gradle-project?rq=1)
suggest to create Android project with `android create project` than add `build.gradle` template for classic Android project [gh.c/N/n-1/b/m/o.n.e.e.g/docs/android/build.gradle](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.gradle/docs/android/build.gradle).
(That would allow to develop in any IDE, as old structure is more widely adopted)

Of course there will be some `gradle init` options or `android create` (from SDK) in the future.

#### UPDATE:

Android SDK 19 has `android` CLI `-g` option that allows to use gradle template. You might also need to specify android gradle plugin version with CLI `-v` option, check [android gradle plugin compatibility table](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility). Example command to create the project that uses android gradle plugin (v 0.10) to add gradle support.

```
android create project \
    --gradle \
    --gradle-version 0.10 \
    --activity Main \
    --package com.example.app \
    --target android-19 \
    --path AppWithGradleTemplate
```

or for buildTools 19.1+, use a newer version of the Gradle Android plugin via **`--gradle-version`**:

```
android create project \
    --gradle \
    --gradle-version 0.11.+ \
    --activity Main \
    --package com.example.app \
    --target android-25 \
    --path AppWithGradleTemplate
```

check `android create project -h` for help

However Android Studio 0.6.1 failed to open it correctly (no sources shown), because it took first project folder (that is `gradle`) as module folder -> you need to Import, not just open.

In Eclipse it was with a trick of regarding `src` folder as root of the project.

`.classpath` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="java"/><!--ADJUSTED HERE -->
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

And `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
   //{ for Android Gradle as Eclipse project
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest.setRoot('../tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    //}
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:10'
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

[image]

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle

read at http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/

Comment: `gradle assembleDebug` fails with `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.8`. How to you choose the gradle version?

Comment: `$ android create project -h
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
android update sdk`  Any other way?

Comment: `android create project` was removed in SDK tools 26.0.1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46994747/895245

Answer (score 16):

**`android create project` was removed in SDK tools 26.0.1**

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/906942/android-update-project-path-target-android-25-on-ubuntu-16-04 for more details

Trying to use it fails with:

```
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command "project create"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

**Workaround: Android Studio template + copy helper script**

The best workaround I have is to:

- create a new Gradle project manually from the Android Studio GUI
- use a helper script to copy that template around, renaming classes in the process

The following helper script allows you to do:

```
./template NewAppName AppTemplateProject
```

to get a new app `NewAppName` from an existing `AppTemplateProject` created with Android studio:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex
new="$1"
shift
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  old="$1"
  shift
else
  old='Min'
fi
old="$(echo "$old" | sed -E 's/\/$//')"
new="$(echo "$new" | sed -E 's/\/$//')"
new_lower="$(echo "$new" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')"
old_lower="$(echo "$old" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')"
cp -r "$old" "$new"
cd "$new"
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/${old}/${new}/g"
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/${old_lower}/${new_lower}/g"
cd 'app/src/main/java/com/cirosantilli/android_cheat'
```

GitHub upstream: https://github.com/cirosantilli/android-cheat/blob/0e6b7462705179658b48d0e2e27f0dbce308393c/gradle/template

Yes it is not perfect. But CLI support appears secondary to Google, so what can you do :-(

Comment: Should be listed in https://github.com/cirosantilli/android-cheat/blob/master/gradle.md

Comment: @PaulVerest thanks for feedback. I'm in the process of moving all the examples to gradle, and the first ones are under https://github.com/cirosantilli/android-cheat/tree/master/gradle atm. When that migration is done, I will just move the gradle/ dir to toplevel.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution [PHP Android CLI](https://github.com/AnandPilania/php-android-cli)

Just run:

```
phpandroid create HelloWorld com.example.helloworld
```

and your project is scaffolded with latest android-studio parameters, like, compile & target SDK is 29, buildToolsVersion is 29.0.1 & minSdk is 16.

If you want to change, like, want to set minSdk to 14:

```
phpandroid create PROJECT PACKAGE --minSdk=14
```

> PHP Android CLI can also create Variants and modules (application/library):

```
phpandroid create PROJECT PACKAGE --modules=common:library,admin --variants=free:type,paid:type,php:backend,firebase:backend
```

this will generate 2 applications, `app`, `admin` & a library `common`.
`App` has 2 dimensions: `type` & `backend`
4 variants: `free` & `paid` of `type` dimension; `php` & `firebase` variant of `backend` dimension.