# How to create a minimal Android gradle project?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I need to setup a minimal Gradle & Android SDK project in order to test that a specific library can be used in this environment.

`gradle init` does not provide any options for Android.

How should I create a minimal compilable project for Android with gradle?

Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801042/how-to-create-android-project-with-gradle-from-command-line) are outdated and were of no help for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out this:

Use Gradle 6.1.1 and Android SDK 29.

**settings.gradle**

*empty*

**build.gradle** (example from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build)):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android { compileSdkVersion 29 }
repositories { jcenter() }
```

**src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example">
</manifest>
```

Plenty of android boilerplates are also available [on Github](https://github.com/search?q=android%20boilerplate)

Comment: Is `allprojects` block really necessary?

Comment: @andreoss not necessary, just for convenience on multi-module project. Otherwise, that block has to be copied and pasted on each module's `build.gradle`, including the `app` module.